# $location not defined when using only ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started using ui router instead of ng-route and I have the following error:

ReferenceError: $location is not defined
    at new homeController (app.js:345:18)
    at invoke (angular.js:3762:17)
    at http://localhost:8080/shop/resources/lib/angular/angular-ui-router.js:3807:21

My controller:

```
function headerController($scope, $location){
   var host = $location.host();
}
```

Do I have to include ng-route as dependency in my module?

Thanks.

Comment: In the error it is about `homeController`, and in your code you named it `headerController`

Comment: You are right. I was missing $location in homeController. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, added that as an answer then:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You injected `$location` in `headerController` instead of `homeController`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your module definition you need to include it:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.router'])
```